# MongoDB: Update user data based on varying JSON POST data

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

Using a MEAN environment (including mongoose for database access) I send varying JSON data from a web form (user profile input form) to my server. There, I want to update the user's document based on the data sent to my server. My problem: as some user related information is optional I end with a broad variety of JSON objects that are sent to my server, e.g.

```
1) {(name: 'fooman', email: 'foo@man.com')}
2) {(name: 'fooman', email: 'foo@man.com', adress:'fooadress')}
3) {(name: 'fooman', email: 'foo@man.com', hasdog:'true')}
4) {(name: 'fooman', email: 'foo@man.com', location: 'footown')}
```

On the server side, I end up checking every possible JSON structure to then finally update the user's document using an appropriate mongoose instruction like:

```
User.update({ _id: userid}, {name: json.name, email: json.email}) ->for case 1

User.update({ _id: userid}, {name: json.name, email: json.email, hasdog: true}) ->for case 3
```

As you can see, this leads me to somewhat ugly and redundant code. I was hoping for some architecture advice of how to avoid this.

Comment: No no, this is _great_ code. Seriously, the alternative - pushing the JSON directly or `Object.assign`ing properties magically is the problematic one - because users might be able to push `admin: true` and stuff like that - GitHub basically got hacked because of a similar bug, twice. The very best you can do is to whitelist properties and then iterate and assign them (if they match the whitelist) in a for loop.

Comment: The whitelist idea is much better and future-proof, it can be implemented very easily with `Array.every`: http://jsbin.com/velubunozi/edit?js,output The `eval` is just there for the demo, you should obviously use a safer way to build your object (JSON.parse for example).

Comment: Great, thanks so far for your input! As I am using Mongoose, I need to define data models for every collection anyways, clearly listing all valid properties. Everything apart from what is listed in those models won't be saved anyways. Is that property-whitelist enough?

Comment: @IgorP. Probably not, as the risk is in allowing users to set any of the defined fields, even those that they shouldn't be able to modify (e.g. username), now and in the future as more fields are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up your `update` object programmatically by pulling the valid (whitelisted) fields from the request:

```
var request = {name: 'fooman', email: 'foo@man.com', hasdog: true, password: 'hack'};
var whitelist = ['name', 'email', 'address', 'hasdog', 'location'];
var update = {};

// Add the whitelisted fields in the request to the update object.
for (var ix in whitelist) {
    var field = whitelist[ix];
    if (request.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        update[field] = request[field];
    }
}
User.update({ _id: userid }, update);
```